# Sharing Data with the Class that does not extends Activity

Tags: sockets, android-intent, android-activity, tcpclient, extends

I have made a `TCP` client for android using socket. However, the program that I have does not allow me to dynamically input the server address. Also i cannot use intent to transfer String from `MainActivity` because my `TcpClient.java` does not extends to `Activity`. What logic shall I implement so that I can dynamically set server address and connect to any server I wish..

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_settings:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SETTINGS);
                break;

            }

            return true;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_SETTINGS:
               saveData();
                break;

            }

        }

        public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TcpClient> {

            @Override
            protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

                //we create a TCPClient object and
                mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                    @Override
                    //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                    public void messageReceived(String message) {
                        //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                        publishProgress(message);
                    }
                });
                mTcpClient.run(serverip, serverport);

               return null;
            }

        }


        //call it at Activity startup onStart() for example
        public void loadData(){

               int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
               SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
               mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS, mode);
               serverip = mySharedPreferences.getString("IP", serverip);
               serverport = mySharedPreferences.getInt("Port", serverport);
           }

           // Call it whenever you modify the values
           public void saveData()
           {
               int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
               SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
               mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS, mode);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
               editor.putString("IP", serverip);
               editor.putInt("Port", serverport);
               editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Server Settings Saved" + serverip + serverport , 
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

}

This is not saving the data. Its showing null0 on the Toast.Also these are the variables declared for the above code

```
public static final String MYPREFS = "192.168.1.3";
public String serverip;
public int serverport;
```

Preferences.java

```
package com.example.homauto;
```

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity{

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

}

I am a newbie to programming..
Here is the website from where i took the references..[Android TCP Connection tutorial](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html)

Comment: Can you post the code of the MainActivity where you start/call the TcpClient? Is it (TcpClient) a service a thread?

Comment: I hope this is what your required...

Comment: Change the variable MYPREFS from `"192.168.1.3"` to `"Config.dat"`  also initialize the other two variables like for example: ` public String serverip = "192.168.1.3";` and `public int serverport = 4444;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are a couple of thing you can do in order to pass the IP and Port to the TCPClient class. For me the easiest one is to declare the run method as follows:

```
public void run(String srvIP, int srvPort)
{
    mRun = true;
    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(srvIP);
        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, srvPort);
```

You must call it like this:

```
 mTcpClient.run("ServerIP", ServerPort);
 like this: mTcpClient.run("192.168.1.25", 4444);
```

Other possibility is to change the create method and put those parameters there,

```
// You have to remove the final in these variables
public static String SERVERIP = "192.168.0.102"; //your computer IP address
public static int SERVERPORT = 4444;
 public TCPClient(String srvIP, int srvPort, OnMessageReceived listener) {
        SERVERIP=srvIP;
        SERVERPORT=srvPort;
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }
```

and you instantiate the class like this:

```
mTcpClient = new TcpClient(ServerIP, ServerPort, new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived()
```

Now, in your application (main activity) you need to put a dialog or another activity in order to ask the user for the IP and port to connect to before you launch the TCPClient class, in your case the AsyncTask.

I'd put an action bar menu and when clicked show a dialog to ask for those values.

Also, you may save the values so that you have them for future use (in MainActivity):

```
// call it at Activity startup onStart() for example
public void loadData()
{
    int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
    mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Typedefs.saveConfigsFileName, mode);
    serverIP = mySharedPreferences.getString("IP", serverIP);
    serverPort = mySharedPreferences.getInt("Port", serverPort);
}

// Call it whenever you modify the values
public void saveData()
{
    int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
    mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Typedefs.saveConfigsFileName, mode);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("IP", serverIP);
    editor.putInt("Port", serverPort);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the useful explanation.. I got every bit of it except for the Typedefs.saveConfigsFileName... Could explain me this part?

Comment: Sorry about that, I pasted from an application of mine. It's just a String variable containing a file name, for example: "MyFile.dat", "Config.def" whatever you like it to name it.

Comment: I m sorry but i still didn't get what it meant... Also while calling the run() func, you've already sent a string(ip address). i want to send a string variable instead of that. EDIT: yup i changed it to string variable but i m stuck only at the sharedprefs part

Comment: Ok, I'll explain it: Typedefs is a class of mine where I have a static variable called saveConfigsFileName and it is declared like this:
`String static final saveConfigFileName = "Config.dat";`
So, in your activity you shuld change `typedefs.saveConfigFilename` with `"Config.dat"` or any other name you prefer.

Comment: Thanx i understood what you told... However i m having trouble saving the data.. check the code in the question i've edited..

Comment: Change the variable MYPREFS from `"192.168.1.3"` to `"Config.dat"`  also initialize the other two variables like for example: `public String serverip = "192.168.1.3";` and `public int serverport = 4444;`

Comment: Yup done... But when i return from preferencescreeen i still get a Toast with default ip and port... Its still not saving my preference..

Comment: That's because in you preference activity you are not updating the proper variables. You should change the serverip and serverport declared in the MainActivity. Check that.

Comment: I would be really grateful if you could explain me... Sorry m acting like a big n00b.. I've updated OP with Preferences.java.. but its almost empty.What would you like me to fill it with? Whats wrong it serverip and serverport? do u want me to change the variable name?